# Rails 4 has_many :through association: use Devise current_user in other parent model after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, callback, has-many-through

I have three models, with a `has_many :through` association :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

The join `Administration` model has the following attributes:

```
id
user_id
calendar_id
role
```

Here are my current routes:

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'account'

resources :users do
  resources :calendars
end
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the `Calendars#create` code:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_calendar_path(@user,@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Whenever a `user` creates a new `calendar`, I want to assign this particular `user` a `role` — in the `administration` join model — of "Owner".

I thought the best way to do that would be to use an `after_create` callback in the `calendar` model, as follows:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations

  after_create :set_default_role

  protected

  def set_default_role
    current_user.calendar.role = "Owner"
  end

end
```

However, when I go on and try to create a new calendar, I get the following error:

```
NameError in CalendarsController#create
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Calendar:0x007f88f8f26998>

Extracted source (around line #10):

  def set_default_role
    current_user.calendar.role = "Owner"
  end

end
```

After some research, I found [this question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-ways-to-get-current-user-detail-in-models) with the following answer:

> It is not good practice for the model to directly have knowledge of
>   the current user; this is an application 'state' or session related
>   issue. The controllers should be managing the current user.

I have to say that I am somewhat confused: a general principle is to keep controllers skinny, by placing the logic in the models. But, the above answer suggests to do the opposite because the model should no be aware of the current user.

So, to get back to my initial question: how can I define a default role for a user when he creates a new calendar?

Should I go with an `after_create` callback, use something else rather than `current_user` to get his `id`, or go with a completely different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**
The model don't have a current_user. Remove set_default_role form Calendar model  and add to Administration model:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar

  before_create :set_default_role

  def set_default_role
    self.role = "Owner"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the change you recommend in the Calendar model. However, I am not sure I get the part in the Calendars controller. I updated my question with the code from my Calendars controller.

Comment: Should I just use the code you recommend in the `Calendar` model.

Comment: When I add `after_create :set_default_role protected def set_default_role self.role = "Owner" end end` in my Calendar model and try to create a new calendar, I get the following error: `NoMethodError in CalendarsController#create
undefined method 'role=' for #<Calendar:0x007f88fc8a9e40>`

Comment: Do you have a "role" field in the calendars table?

Comment: and change "after_create" to "before_create"

Comment: The `role` field is not in the `calendars` table: it is in the `administrations` table, which is the join table between the `users` table and the `calendars` table. Indeed, there is no point in adding a `role` to `calendar`, since a `role` only exists at the intersection of a `user` and a `calendar`.

Comment: ok, sorry i don't see that. than is better to add set_default_role method to Administration model (i change the answer).

Answer (score 0):

add this to the CalendarsController create action:

```
@calendar.administrations.first.role = 'Owner'
```

and i think it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your code, except for the `first` part. May I ask you why you recommend this?

Comment: I tried your code. The calendar is created. However, when I check in the console, the role is still set to `nil`. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: you have :has_many association in the Calendal model so @calendar.administratins will return an array of administrations. at creation there will be 1 element. so the .first will return that.

Comment: Thanks. Agree. But when I tried this code, it did not work unfortunately, as the role was still nil in the console. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Try out .build instead of .create when you first create the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.

First, in `User` model, I defined the following method:

```
def set_default_role(calendar_id, role)
  self.administrations.find_by(calendar_id: calendar_id).update(role: role)
end
```

Then, I updated `Calendars#Create` as follows:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @calendar = @user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @calendar.save
      current_user.set_default_role(@calendar.id, 'Owner')
      format.html { redirect_to user_calendar_path(@user,@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @calendar }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, whenever a `user` creates a new `calendar`, if the new `calendar` is saved, then the `current_user` is assigned by default the `role` of owner.